# PhoneGap 3.3.0 aka Cordova Vs PhoneGap 3.2.0

Tags: android, ios, xcode, eclipse, cordova

I am a newbie to PhoneGap and just installed PhoneGap 3.3.0 (is the default version through npm) through npm installer and created app in  [PhoneGap site](http://phonegap.com/install/)

```
C:\> npm install -g phonegap

$ phonegap create my-app
$ cd my-app
$ phonegap run android
```

Then I followed the docs, which is confusing - for [3.3.0 version CLI commands](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) mentioned in docs are cordova whereas for 3.2.0 it is phonegap. And also in the install steps the command mentioned is phonegap not cordova.

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Also I have followed the steps to develop in IDE - Eclipse, but for 3.3.0 there are no steps provided and the folders and files seems to be different.

At some point I tried both the commands to create app, when I use cordova and selected the project by creating an existing Android project, the folders are different from the app created using phonegap.

My questions are:

1. Which CLI to use? [I read somewhere PhoneGap supports more addons/plugins than Cordova]
2. Can I work on the project using Eclipse or Xcode - please provide some guidelines for 3.3.0 to work in IDE environment?
3. Can I use Xcode to develop an Android app also?

Comment: The Phonegap docs might have some stuff that says Cordova because to generate their docs, they probably just take the Cordova docs and replace "Cordova" with "Phoengap." There are a few instances in Cordova docs where it still/accidentally says "Phonegap." Currently the only difference btwn the two that I am aware of is how you specify plugins for Phonegap build and how you can "build locally" with Phonegap (which would be the default for Cordova.)

Comment: @MBillau Which is what confusing new bies.. thanks!

Comment: These links have more explanation about the relationship between PhoneGap and Cordova
[Devgeeks blog](http://blog.devgeeks.org/post/73789983750/cordova-vs-phonegap-an-update) and 
[Telerik blog](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-03-26/demystifying-apache-cordova-and-phonegap)

Comment: Very useful explanation on the changes from PhoneGap 3.0 [PhoneGap 3.0 – Stuff You Should Know](http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/) from Devgirls weblog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Phonegap is just Adobe's branded version of Apache Cordova. If you want to take advantage of building your applications in Adobe's cloud, you will use Phonegap (this could be useful if you don't have a mac to build your iOS apps.) Because Phonegap is built on top of Cordova and is basically the same with some cloud integration, any plugin written for Phonegap must work for Cordova as well (it's not true to say a Cordova plugin will work on Phonegap though, since plugin's need to do some special stuff to work within Adobe's build system.) It might be true that Adobe offers support for certain plugins, but if they do I am unaware of it.
2. Yes, you can use the Cordova (or Phonegap) CLI to create the basic project structure, then you can actually develop the project with your choice of IDE. Most people will probably not actually use Eclipse or Xcode unless they are doing plugin development - this is because with Cordova you will be developing a mobile app with HTML5 technologies, and historically Eclipse/Xcode are not good for this type of development. You can find guides on the Cordova docs about how to set up your development workflow with the IDEs: [iOS Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide) and [Android Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)
3. [It looks possible](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/11/20/how-to-use-xcode-for-android-projects/) but it might be a lot of work for little reward.

Comment: Probably I can use Dreamweaver or Notepad++ instead of Eclipse/Xcode.

Comment: These links have more explanation about the relationship between PhoneGap and Cordova
[Devgeeks blog](http://blog.devgeeks.org/post/73789983750/cordova-vs-phonegap-an-update) and 
[Telerik blog](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-03-26/demystifying-apache-cordova-and-phonegap)

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap is basically a wrapper. After downloading the phonegap, use the create command that's located inside respective OS bin folder. It will create the basic infrastructure to develop the application. Basically you can work with Eclipse or XCode as per your convenience. It's just a matter of copying the assets folder to the respective wrapper generated code later.